# A proof of Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

In an attempt to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539319/how-to-go-from-radon-nikodym-derivative-to-classical-derivative-in-change-of-var) question, I have encountered a [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1037852/368425) that appeals to Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem. I'm trying to fill in the detail of the proof sketch given in a lecture note.

> **Lebesgue’s Differentiation** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f \in L_1(\Omega)$. Then for a.e. $x \in \Omega$, we have
> $$
> f(x) = \lim _{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)} f(y) \mathrm d y.
> $$
> Here $B(x, r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$, and $|E|$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $E \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

**My attempt:** We define the Hardy–Littlewood [maximal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function) $Mf: \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ of $f$ by
$$
(M f)(x) :=\sup _{r>0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)} |f(y)| \mathrm d y \quad \forall x \in \Omega.
$$

Then $Mf$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539584/the-hardy-littlewood-maximal-function-is-borel-measurable) Borel measurable.

> **Lemma:** Let $A_t := \left\{x \in \Omega \mid (M f)(x)>t\right\}$. Then
> $$
> \left|A_t\right| \leq \frac{3^n}{t} \int_{\Omega} |f|  \quad \forall t>0.
> $$
>
> **Proof:** For each $x \in A_t$, there is $r_x>0$ such that
> $$
> t < \frac{1}{|B(x, r_x)|} \int_{B(x, r_x)} |f|  \quad \text{or} \quad  |B(x, r_x)| < \frac{1}{t} \int_{B(x, r_x)} |f|.
> $$
> Let $K$ be a compact subset of $A_t$. Clearly, $\{B(x, r_{x})\}_{x \in A_t}$ covers $K$. So there is a finite subcover. By Vitali covering lemma, there is a **disjoint** finite subfamily $\left\{B\left(x_i, r_i\right)\right\}_{i=1}^k$ such that $K \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k B\left(x_i, 3 r_i\right)$. Hence
> $$
> |K| \le \sum_{i=1}^k |B\left(x_i, 3 r_i\right)| \le 3^n\sum_{i=1}^k |B\left(x_i, r_i\right)| \le \frac{3^n}{t}  \sum_{i=1}^k \int_{B(x_i, r_i)} |f| \le \frac{3^n}{t} \int_\Omega |f|.
> $$

Because Lebesgue measure is tight, we have
$$
|A_t| \le \frac{3^n}{t} \int_\Omega |f|.
$$

It suffices to prove that for a.e. $x \in \Omega$, we have
$$
\limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)} |f - f(x)| = 0.
$$

Now we fix $g \in C_b(\Omega)$. Then
$$
\limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |g - g(x)| = 0.
$$

As such,
$$
\begin{align}
& \limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |f - f(x)| \\
\le & \limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |g - g(x)| + \limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |f - g| + |f(x) - g(x)| \\
= & \limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |f - g| + |f(x) - g(x)| \\
\le & M (|f-g|) (x) + |f(x) - g(x)|.
\end{align}
$$

Now we fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then
$$
\limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |f - f(x)| > \varepsilon \implies \left [ M (|f-g|) (x) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad |f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right ].
$$

By Tshebyshev's inequality,
$$
\left | \left \{ x \in \Omega \,\middle\vert\, |f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right \}\right | \le \frac{2}{\varepsilon} \int_\Omega |f-g|.
$$

By above **Lemma**,
$$
\left | \left \{ x \in \Omega \,\middle\vert\, M (|f-g|) (x) > \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right \}\right | \le \frac{2\cdot 3^n}{\varepsilon} \int_{\Omega} |f-g|.
$$

So there is some constant $C>0$ (that depends only on $n$) such that
$$
\left | \left \{ x \in \Omega \,\middle\vert\, \limsup_{r \searrow 0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |f - f(x)| > \varepsilon \right \}\right | \le \frac{C}{\varepsilon} \int_{\Omega} |f-g|.
$$

Because $C_b(\Omega)$ is dense in $L_1(\Omega)$, for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$ we have that
$$
\frac{C}{\varepsilon} \int_{\Omega} |f-g|
$$
can be arbitrarily small. This completes the proof.